# Parse content-page using Regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a Java code using regex to parse a content-page extracted from a PDF document.

In a string the regex must match: a digit (up to three) followed by a space (or many) followed by a word (or many [word: any sequence of characters]). And vise versa: (word(s) space(s) digit(s)), they all must be in the string. Also considering leading spaces and be case insensitive.

The extracted content-page could look something like this:

> Directors’ responsibilities 8
>
> Corporate governance 9
>
> Remuneration report 10

the numbering-style is not consistent and number of spaces between digit and string do vary, so it could also look like:

> 01    Contents
>
> 02    Strategy and highlights
>
> 04    Chairman’s statement

The regex i'm using matches any number of words followed by any number of spaces and then a number of no more than 3 digits:

```
(?i)([a-z\\s])*[0-9]{1,3}(?i)
```

It works but not quite well, can't tell what I'm doing wrong? and I wish there is a way to detect both numbering-style (having the page numbers to the left or right of the string)  instead of repeating the regex and flip the order.

Cheers

Comment: When you ask for a regex the most important thing is to say very specifically what the pattern is that the text will follow, it's not always possible to tell from examples

Comment: For one, the "Chairman's statement" example contains a ' which you are not accounting for in your regex.

Comment: @aaronman I mentioned that above: 
*The regex i'm using matches any number of words followed by any number of spaces and then a number of no more than 3 digits*. But maybe I wasn't clear enough, will make sure to do so next time. Cheers

Comment: @increment1, I remove punctuations before passing the String, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user1980638 that's exactly my point, what can be considered a word

Comment: @aaronman Word: any sequence of characters, I have updated the question. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match phrases you should include any punctuation you want to match in your regex. AFAIK there is no way in regex to say if a phrase is "before or after", so you should flip one and append it with a `|`. Something along the lines of:

`[a-zA-Z'".,!\s]+\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z'".,!\s]+`

Also, you don't need two instances of `(?i)`, as the regex will apply the case insensitivity until the end of the string or if it encounters a `(?-i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern with **multiline mode**, if there is always a number before or after each items:

```
"^(?:(?<nb1>\\d{1,3}) +)?(?<item>\\S+(?: +\\S+)*?)(?: +(?<nb2>\\d{1,3})|$)"
```

Then you can use `m.group('nb1')+m.group('nb2')` to always obtain the number for each whole match.

But if you must check there is at least a number, you must repeat the whole pattern:

```
"^(?:(?<nb1>\\d{1,3}) +(?<item1>\\S+(?: +\\S+)*)|(?<item2>\\S+(?: +\\S+)*) +(?<nb2>\\d{1,3})$"
```

Then:

```
item = m.group('item1')+m.group('item2');
nb = m.group('nb1')+m.group('nb2');
```

Notice: since the patterns are anchored at the begining and at the end, it is possible that you have to add some optional spaces to do them work: `^\\s*` and `\\s*$`

Comment: Never used *multliline mode* before, looks great, thanks a lot for the answer.
The first one works quite well, but you are right I need it to find at least one digit.
Using the second regex, I got a no match found error, so I modified the regex to:
`"^(?:(?<nb1>\\d{1,3}) +)?(?<item1>\\S+(?: +\\S+)*?)(?<item2>\\S+(?: +\\S+)*?)(?: +(?<nb2>\\d{1,3})|$)";`

It works correctly but for some reason it skips the last character at the last match it finds. Any reason why?